# Как встроить консоль windows в окно UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Мне нужно отправить команду из TextBox (UWP -универсального приложения windows) в консоль.

И вывести результат в окно TextBox.

Можете дать ссылку на какой-то пример с UWP?

Comment: Думаю, вы неправильно поняли задачу, и вам нужен реально `Process.Start` (или какой там у него аналог под UWP).

Comment: Что-то я совсем не уверен, что у UWP есть такая возможность. Там же приложения работают с WinRT, которая есть подмножество .Net. У дестопа есть консоль, а вин-телефона же ее нет, а приложение универсальное, т.е. должно без изменений работать и там и там.